# Finding limit superior and inferior

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(S_n) = (5, -1/2, 2/3, -1/4, 4/5, -1/6, 6/7,.....)$

Find the set $S$ of subsequential limits, limit superior, and limit inferior.

Clearly there are two patterns... $\{-\frac12, -\frac14, -\frac16,\cdots \}$ and  $\{ \frac23,  \frac45, \frac67, \cdots \}$

So it seems the limit superior would be $1$ and the limit inferior would be $0$.
However, my concern is $5$ in the sequence. Does that effect the above values?

Comment: No, as limits superior and inferior only concern the tail of the sequence.

Comment: No.  Limits are such that for $n > N$ for arbitrary large n.  Any isolated blip at some finite specific spot do not affect the "overall eventual behavior".

Comment: Okay thanks. So the Limit inferior is 0 and superior 1, the 5 doesnt matter? Makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Recall that

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sup_{m\ge n}a_m\right)$$

So once we have $n=2$, we no longer worry about the $5$.

Answer (score 0):

You have

$S_1=5$ and for $n\geq 1$,

$$S_{2n}=-\frac{1}{2n}$$

$$S_{2n+1}=\frac{2n}{2n+1}$$

thus

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}S_{2n}=0$$

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}S_{2n+1}=1$$

finally,

$$\limsup S_n =1 , \liminf S_n=0$$